# Unable to deploy Django on local with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my first django web app. My knowledge in web servers is near by 0. After having configured everything, I get `502 Bad Gateway` when trying to access my page.

### Gunicorn command

`sudo gunicorn website.wsgi --log-level debug -u root -group root`. This allow me to access my app on `localhost:8000`, but the medias and static are not working.

### Nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost.kevin.lo;
        charset utf-8;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/oktomus.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/oktomus.error.log;

        location /media {
            alias /home/oktomus/workspace/code/web/website-prod/media;
        }

        location /static {
            alias /home/oktomus/workspace/code/web/website-prod/static;
        }

        location / {
            include fastcgi_params;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;

        }

    }
}
```

### Nginx error

The error log when I try too access the app on port 80.

```
2017/07/05 21:06:20 [error] 9767#9767: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.kevin.lo, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://[::1]:8000", host: "localhost"
2017/07/05 21:07:00 [error] 9767#9767: *7 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.kevin.lo, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "localhost"
2017/07/05 21:07:31 [error] 9767#9767: *7 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.kevin.lo, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8000", host: "localhost"
2017/07/05 21:07:31 [error] 9767#9767: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.kevin.lo, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://[::1]:8000", host: "localhost"
```

### Gunicorn output

This is what output when I try to access the app and then stop the browser after few seconds.

```
[10024] [DEBUG] Ignored premature client disconnection. No more data after: b'\x01\x01\x00\x01\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x04\x00\x01\x03\x06\x02\x00\x0c\x00QUERY_STRING\x0e\x03REQUEST_METHODGET\x0c\x00CONTENT_TYPE\x0e\x00CONTENT_LENGTH\x0b\x01SCRIPT_NAME/\x0b\x01REQUEST_URI/\x0c\x01DOCUMENT_URI/\r\x0fDOCUMENT_ROOT/etc/nginx/html\x0f\x08SERVER_PROTOCOLHTTP/1.1\x0e\x04REQUEST_SCHEMEhttp\x11\x07GATEWAY_INTERFACECGI/1.1\x0f\x0cSERVER_SOFTWAREnginx/1.12.0\x0b\tREMOTE_ADDR127.0.0.1\x0b\x05REMOTE_PORT37886\x0b\tSERVER_ADDR127.0.0.1\x0b\x02SERVER_PORT80\x0b\x12SERVER_NAMElocalhost.kevin.lo\x0f\x03REDIRECT_STATUS200\t\tHTTP_HOSTlocalhost\x0fDHTTP_USER_AGENTMozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0\x0b?HTTP_ACCEPTtext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\x14\x0eHTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGEen-US,en;q=0.5\x14\rHTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODINGgzip, deflate\x0bJHTTP_COOKIEcsrftoken=bOeYkxXdfepIfgwiNnNMeT21NznPM3y1fAR07wp8MyCJtAAbrXdiVfHZxbmuSx0l\x08\x01HTTP_DNT1\x0f\nHTTP_CONNECTIONkeep-alive\x1e\x01HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS1\x00\x00\x01\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

And if I don't stop the browser, I land on 502 nginx Bad Gateway, and gunicorn outputs this.

```
[2017-07-05 21:29:04 +0200] [10135] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10146)
```

I have readed the nginx beginer's guide which helped me understand few things, but still I don't know what to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you using fastcgi_pass in your nginx config? You're not using fastcgi anywhere.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because many tutorials say to use it... What should I use ?

Comment: Show me one that does. Gunicorn - like almost any Python web server - uses wsgi. But the gunicorn docs themselves have a perfectly working example of an nginx configuration to use; there is no reason to follow anything else.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the tip. I was following really old tutorials, and in french ^^ I'll read the gunicorn doc.

Comment: I got a similar error when trying to talk to gunicorn in HTTPS through nginx even though it was just serving HTTP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was just following too old tutorials. I readed the gunicorn documentation, and it works perfectly.

Comment: specifying what you did (with code example) would be helpful

Comment: @MIkee I don't remember anymore but I know that the doc was very clear. It's just that I wasn't experienced enough to understand everything on the first try.